# VBA Excel - Delete columns if a cell is explicitly equal to zero

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will take a specific worksheet in my workbook **go through a certain row and if a cell is explicitly = 0 then delete that column and the next four columns to the right**.

I have little experience with VB so I am struggling to get my head around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I have so far :

```
Sub SaveAsW()

Dim strFilename As String
Dim strpath As String
Dim curCell As Range
Dim TempValue, ColNr, RowNr, SecCol

RowNr = 35

strpath = Sheets("Rebooking Calculations").Range("AK9").Text
strFilename = Sheets("Ticket Input").Range("M10").Text

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tickets (1-48)").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    For ColNr = 8 To 320
        TempValue = Cells(RowNr, ColNr)
        If (Application.IsNumber(TempValue)) And TempValue.Value = 0 Then
            For SecCol = 1 To 4
                Cells.EntireColumn.Delete
            Next SecCol
        End If
    Next ColNr
    .SaveAs strpath & "\" & strFilename & "(1-48)" & ".xls"
    .Close 0
End With
```

UPDATE:

w/ help this is how I solved my problem.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tickets (1-48)").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    For ColNr = 8 To 250
        If Cells(RowNr, ColNr - 1) = "0" Then
            TempValue = Cells(RowNr, ColNr - 1)
            If TempValue = "0" Then
                For i = 0 To 9
                    Cells(RowNr, ColNr - 1).Select
                    Cells(RowNr, ColNr - 1).EntireColumn.Delete
                Next i
            ColNr = ColNr - 1
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next ColNr
    .SaveAs strpath & "\" & strFilename & "(1-48)" & ".xls"
    .Close 0
End With
```

Thanks. (NB: I ended up having to delete the following 9 columns hence the loop)

Comment: Could you provide some test data?

Comment: We know your requirement. What about the code? Is it work or give an error? If give error, say line which give error.

Comment: Why so many down votes? And no need for test data here, the requirement is pretty clear and the code pretty close, so just correct and point mistakes or inaccuracies in it...

Comment: No need to use `.Select` here mate, get rid of `Cells(RowNr, ColNr - 1).Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a good start, but there was some issues in your code :

First, when you delete rows or columns, it is usually easier to decrease your variable to avoid missing rows/columns as they will shift when you delete one (i.e. column (i+1) will become column (i) after deletion of the initial column (i) and you'll increment to (i+1) and miss the initial (i+1) to restart at initial (i+2)).

So changed your loop to avoid that.

The idea of a temp variable to improve efficiency was good but I think that the test `IsNumber(TempValue)` won't work as you assigned it to a variable that is typed, so it'll be better to work directly here with the cells.

Finaly, the `Cells.EntireColumn.Delete` will be more accurate if your specify the specific cell with row and column or directly delete the 5 columns without looping, see corrected code :

```
Sub SaveAsW()

Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    strFilename As String, _
    strPath As String, _
    ColNr As Integer, _
    RowNr As Integer

RowNr = 35

strPath = Sheets("Rebooking Calculations").Range("AK9").Text
strFilename = Sheets("Ticket Input").Range("M10").Text

Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tickets (1-48)")

With Ws
    '.Copy
    For ColNr = 320 To 8 Step -1
        If (Application.IsNumber(.Cells(RowNr, ColNr))) And .Cells(RowNr, ColNr) = 0 Then
            .Columns(ColNr & ":" & ColNr + 4).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next ColNr
    .SaveAs strPath & "\" & strFilename & "(1-48)" & ".xls"
    .Close 0
End With

Set Ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Apologies for not supplying test information - it is sensative to my job so was hard to provide.

Comment: Ok, no problem, test data is not really useful most of the time and especially this time... Just detail more what you are trying to do and what is your issue. **If the answer helped you to solved your issue, please accept it to mark the question as answered**. (and later on, use up/down votes, for each post that you fin useful)